# Change in Observable collection not reflected in UI

Tags: wpf, data-binding, observablecollection

I have a proprty o type "Observable collection"...when i add an item it's not geeting reflected in UI ...what am doing wrong...?

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" 
Width="120" SelectedIndex="0"
Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
ItemsSource="{Binding AllPlaces}" 
DisplayMemberPath="PlaceName" 
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedPlace.Value, Mode=TwoWay}" 
VerticalAlignment="Top">
</ComboBox>


// Add the new item to the existing place list, so that it will be refreshed.
ObservableCollection<PlaceDto> existingPlaceList = new ObservableCollection<PlaceDto>();
// Copy all places to a temperory list.
foreach(PlaceDto placeItem in AllPlaces)
{
existingPlaceList.Add(placeItem);
}
// Add new place to existing list
existingPlaceList .Add(newPlace);
AllPlaces= existingPlaceList;
```

Comment: please show the binding in xaml and you adding an element.

Comment: why do you copy all places to a temporary list? just add the place to AllPlaces. AllPlaces.Add(newPlace). The rest is not needed. and initialize the AllPlaces variable in the constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ObservableCollection will notify the GUI if the list changes. However, you're changing the entire list itself with the line AllDivisions = existingPlaceList. You'll have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for the class that contains the AllDivisions property to tell the GUI when you swap out the list.

Comment: Absolutely correct. He should add to the existing observablecollection. Changing the reference will not work.

Comment: I just wanted to add new item to list.                                If I use only this line => AllPlaces.Add(newPlace);..Will it work ?

Comment: @Anish: drop the AllPlaces= existingPlaceList assignment and use AllPlaces just as public property with a getter that returns existingPlaceList, also make existing PlaceList a class instance variable, if you have to empty it use Clear() instead of creating a new list everytime.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367717/silverlight-windows-phone-databinding-noob-question/3368127#3368127